# unable to download or upload the files using ftp script

Tags: php, ftp

i am unable to download or upload the files using ftp script.
 i can connect to ftp server find the size of the file using ftp_size but when i download it using both ftp_get and ftp_fget the file is empty.i cant even seem to see the list of directories using ftp_nlist().please help me out here?

Comment: What code are you currently using? Post it.

Comment: <?php 
echo "hi";
$host='xxxxxxx';
$user='xxxxxxx';
$pwd='xxxxxxx';
$conn=ftp_connect($host);
$log=ftp_login($conn, $user, $pwd);
$rpath='/xxx/xx/xx/xx/asd.txt';
$file=fopen('abc.txt','w');
ftp_fget($conn, $file, $rpath, FTP_ASCII);

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is a server-side language, the files you get using FTP_get() will end up on the server that is running the PHP script.  You need to make sure that the directory on your server that is receiving the files has proper write permissions.  I suggest CHMOD the dir to 777 to make sure that it works.

Comment: CHMOD 777 only for testing only, then set the permissions/ownership correctly

Comment: ok may be the permission may be an issue but then why is ftp_nlist('/') not showing all the directorie